# What does the 'hash' method do in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, hash

Occasionally, when I am looking down the list of selectors that a object responds to, I see `hash` come up. For a while now, I have wondered what it meant, but I never came around to finding out.

I would really appreciate it if you could tell me what the selector does and common uses for doing so.

Comment: Are you familiar with hash function http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function ?

Comment: No, I am not familiar with it.

Comment: taskindoor's questions was meant rhetorical. He implies, that you get familiar with it.

Comment: The question shows no research effort imho. I expect someone who asks about the general purpose of a method to at least look it up in the documentation and then perhaps ask more specifically about the explanation found there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It computes a hash of the object, which is especially useful in HashTables like when the object is used as a key for an `NSDictionary`.

An object `hash` has to have the following properties:

- Two objects of the same class that are to be considered equal should return the same hash
- Two objects with a diffent hash will never be considered as equal
- Two objects with the same hash are not necessary equal to each other; anyway, the more unique the hash is, the better the performance for `NSDictionary` lookup will be.
- If should also be computable as fast as possible to avoid performance issues in dictionaries

For more info, [read the NSObject Protocol documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html)  where this `hash` method is defined.

---

*For example the `hash` function for a string could be the number of characters of this string, or the sum of the ascii codes of its character, or anything similar.*

When you search for a given key in an `NSDictionary`, one solution would be to compare the searched key with all other keys in the dictionary, which would need to loop thru all the keys and call `isEqual` on each key, and that will take a long time if the dictionary have a lot of entries. So instead, Cocoa will compute the hash of the searched key, and compare it with all the (pre-computed) hashes of the keys in the dictionary.

This is much more efficient because it will only need to make comparisons between `NSUInteger` values, even if the keys of the `NSDictionary` are `NSString`s or other objects, so this is really faster.
Once it has found the keys that have the same hash as the hash of the searched key, it can then loop thru all the keys with this hash and compare them with the searched key by calling `isEqual`, but at this stage there will be much less keys to loop thru (and even possibly only one if the hash of the key is really unique)

Comment: A [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) data structure like `NSDictionary` will usually not compare a key to the hashes of every key it has stored. The hash is normally used as a direct index into an array of buckets that contain chains of objects with the same hash (or hash range, depending on the number of buckets).

Answer (score 0):

It's used for implementing efficient [hash tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) in associative array data types such as [`NSDictionary`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsdictionary_class/Reference/Reference.html).